# Centering text in aligned environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath

How can I center the text between the inequalities? ATM it seems that they are right-aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{aligned}
    15               &\leq &C                    &\leq 25 \\
    (\frac{9}{5}) 15 &\leq &(\frac{9}{5}) C      &\leq (\frac{9}{5}) 25 \\
    27               &\leq &(\frac{9}{5}) C      &\leq 45 \\
    27 + 32          &\leq &(\frac{9}{5}) C + 32 &\leq 45 + 32 \\
    59               &\leq &F                    &\leq 77
  \end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The thing is, aren't you telling LaTeX to align things? But what is it aligning? Either one end or the other, whereas you want it to align something in the middle, but isn't that a different kind of thing to want it to do? Maybe another environment would work better here?

Comment: Hmm, I suppose I could use a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an `array` environment may be the way to go.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r}

\newcommand\ninefive{\Bigl(\frac{9}{5}\Bigr)} % shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{array}{R @{{}\le{}} LL @{{}\le{}} L}
    15           &           & C & 25 \\
    \ninefive 15 & \ninefive & C & \ninefive 25 \\
    27           & \ninefive & C & 45 \\
    27 + 32      & \ninefive & C + 32 & 45 + 32 \\
    59           &           & F & 77
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```